# ERROR: [VRFC 10-3353] formal port 'i0' has no actual or default value

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am making a simple 2bit comparator with the following testbench, code and component below.

I keep getting error when i run the simulation
ERROR: [VRFC 10-3353] formal port 'i0' has no actual or default value.

To me the code and logic of it seems fine. I thought the only problem would be the nested for loops since i am not used to ising them yet.

I am using vivado 2020.2

Testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Comparator_2bit_tb is
--  Port ( );
end Comparator_2bit_tb;

architecture Behavioral of Comparator_2bit_tb is
--component instantiation
component Comparator_2bit 
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           eqtot : out STD_LOGIC);
end component Comparator_2bit;


--signal declaration
signal a, b : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
signal eqtot : std_logic;

begin
--component instantiation
uut: Comparator_2bit
port map (a => a, b => b, eqtot => eqtot);

--Test vector generation
test: process
begin
    for i in 0 to 3 loop
        for u in 0 to 3 loop
        a <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(i, 2));
        b <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(u, 2));
        wait for 10ns;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    wait;
end process test;
end Behavioral;
```

Design

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Comparator_2bit is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           eqtot : out STD_LOGIC);
end Comparator_2bit;

architecture Behavioral of Comparator_2bit is
--component declaration
component Comparator_component
Port (  i0 : in STD_LOGIC;
        i1 : in STD_LOGIC;
        z : out STD_LOGIC);     
end component Comparator_component;

--internal signals
signal eq0, eq1: std_logic;

begin
--component instantiation
bit_0: Comparator_component
port map ( a(0) => i0, b(0) => i1, z => eq0);

bit_1: Comparator_component
port map ( a(1) => i0, b(1) => i1, z => eq1);

eqtot <= (eq0 and eq1);

end Behavioral;
```

component

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Comparator_component is
    Port ( i0 : in STD_LOGIC;
           i1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           z : out STD_LOGIC);
end Comparator_component;

architecture Behavioral of Comparator_component is

begin 
z <= (i0 XNOR i1); -- A eq B  
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: An association list using named association associates elements a formal designator is associated with and actual designator formal => actual. Here the formal designators are port names. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.3 Port map aspects (defines formal and actual), 6.5.6.3 Port clauses (a formal of mode in must have an actual or a default value).

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have got the port mapping the wrong way around. For a port map, you need to map:

```
inst : some_component
port map (
  component_port => local_signal_or_port
```

You have these values switched.